# wpf visual state manager with condition

Tags: wpf, animation, expression-blend

i tring to style an itemcontainerstyle of a listbox by changing the **mouseover** and **selected** state .

with something like that

```
   <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#48FF5643"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFF5643"/>
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>


                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
enter code here
```

the problem is that if i have an item selected and i mouse over it it's state change to **mouseoverstate** and i want to avoid that

i have also tried the controltemplate multitriggers with something like

```
   <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
          <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
   </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
```

but it did not work , and there is not **IsMouseLeave** property

hopefully i explain the problem clearly , so any help is welcome

thanks and good day !

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier changing the `ListBoxItem.Background` property using a `Trigger` and some `SystemColors`. Try this instead:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Days}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FFFF5643" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#FFFF5643" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#48FF5643" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

I have a feeling that these `SystemColors` might not work on either Windows 8 or .NET 4.5, but they do with .NET 4 and Windows 7. Let me know if it does what you wanted.

---

UPDATE >>>

*the problem is the mouseLeave, there is no such property on the eventtriggers*

Perhaps you should investigate the [`Trigger` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) further?:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <!--Performed with MouseEnter event-->
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <!--Performed with MouseLeave event-->
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: yes but if an item is selected i do not want it to respond to the mouseover trigger , a solution in my mind would be a combination of VSM and property triggers, so define a selected state with vsm and a mouseover with multi conditions : mouseover and isselected= false.  the problem is the mouseLeave, there is no such property on the eventtriggers